# OSCAR_SEARCH_FACETS for filtering product lists

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I am working on an ecommerce website using django oscar. 
Products are listed and I have to apply filters (e.g. year, price, etc.). Can we use oscar facet for this filtering functionality?

I have tried adding following as per [oscar documentation](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/settings.html#oscar-search-facets), but don't know how to make it work and render on my front end.

```
OSCAR_SEARCH_FACETS = {
'fields': OrderedDict([
    ('product_class', {'name': _('Type'), 'field': 'product_class'}),
    ('rating', {'name': _('Rating'), 'field': 'rating'}),
]),
'queries': OrderedDict([
    ('price_range',
     {
         'name': _('Price range'),
         'field': 'price',
         'queries': [
             # This is a list of (name, query) tuples where the name will
             # be displayed on the front-end.
             (_('0 to 20'), u'[0 TO 20]'),
             (_('20 to 40'), u'[20 TO 40]'),
             (_('40 to 60'), u'[40 TO 60]'),
             (_('60+'), u'[60 TO *]'),
         ]
     }),
])
}
```

Is it even possible to use this for filtering of products, or is there some other way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Simple Answer

Yes, you can use oscar to filter products based on various search facets. You will have to use a search backend other than haystack's simple backend.

The facets that you have mentioned in the code in your question is what is available by default. Oscar offers more fields and queries that can be displayed as search filters. If you want fields that are custom to your application and not indexed by oscar by default(ex. custom product attributes), check out the detailed answer.

### Detailed Answer

On the latest version of oscar, this is how you can add additional filters such as year, brand, occasion which are not present in oscar by default.

**Search Backend**

First, use a search backend other than Haystack's simple backend. Django oscar officially supports Apache Solr([Documentation here](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto/how_to_setup_solr.html)). If you are using the latest version of Solr, you might have to make some changes to *schema.xml* and *solrconfig.xml*

**Indexing Fields**

Certain fields such as *price* of the product or *product_class* are automatically indexed by Django Oscar. If you want to index other fields such as *product attributes*, you will have to edit oscar search app's *search_indexes.py* to specify the new fields to index. The recommended way to fork oscar's search app to specify your own *search_indexes.py*.
Don't forget to reindex the products after you had added new fields to be indexed.

**Specify Search Facets**
The OSCAR_SEARCH_FACETS setting in *settings.py* can be used to specify what facets to display on the front end. Specify the fields and queries for OSCAR_SEARCH_FACETS, restart your server and you will see the new facets on the front end.

Comment: your answear is not detailed at all, for example i have problem with understanding where oscar - make those http://i.imgur.com/EaDcc9V.png?2 fields change theyr position after its being choosed http://i.imgur.com/ObfzssL.png?1 , before choosing, common was down, after choosing it goes up, i looked up in ui.js and it gave me non, because as far as i understanded there is no full detailed info over how oscar maintain search from solr/haystack

Comment: @LighFusion: The question is about how to get custom fields for search facets and not about the ordering of those facets. If you are wondering why the selected facets appear first, you should take a look at oscar/templates/search/partials/facet.html and not ui.js. Facet.html ensures that selected facets are displayed first.

Comment: no facet.html doesnt do that and thats why i said your info isnt full at all, its just same non amount as from documentation page of oscar

Comment: I agree with you. I am sorry for pointing you in the wrong direction. There is a discussion going on [here](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/issues/1655). May be that should give you an idea about how you could fix your problem.

Comment: well acctualy i found out the reason of this bug, and its quite complicated because its affecting facets mungler, the whole code is wrong.Cause its adding elements in dict using for loop, and each time page is being updated the dict send next data in queue, it looks like that `for data in solr.facets` `dict.append(data)`, and we have as result `dict[0] dict[1]`, and after each time page is being refreshed `dict[1] dict[0]`, but instead of that it must be dict[0,1], so the dict data must be predefined according to returned from solr facets count. Its shit code =D they did