# Django-oscar filter products by attribute using OSCAR_SEARCH_FACETS

Tags: python, django, solr, django-oscar

I've setup a new django-oscar installation on Ubuntu 14.04 server.
I have succesfully setup Solr and I have integrated it with heystack.

I have only one product type in my catalogue and its name is "Part". This product type has only one attribute and its called "category_type" and its an option type attribute with an option group with a few values.
What I am trying to do is to add a filter on the frontend that is filtering products by their "category_type" attribute. What I am stuck at is accessing the product attribute in OSCAR_SEARCH_FACETS, I just dont know how to refference this attribute and what is its field name. I will be extremely greatfull if someone give me a more detailed explanation of how to add custom attributes to the OSCAR_SEARCH_FACETS.

Comment: I had answered something similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32710792/oscar-search-facets-for-filtering-product-lists/35832194#35832194). Hope it helps.